# Insert Query not working in the form

Tags: database, forms, sql

Many people has asked the same question, I have read those things and mine is different,

I am trying to insert some values inside the database from the form but it's not getting inserted

I have a table in the database having 6 columns wanted to insert some values inside only of 4 columns

**Table Name: wp_contactus**

### 6 Columns

- id
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- query
- reg_date

This is the code for inserting only in the 4 columns

### 4 Columns

- firstname
- secondname
- email
- query

  ```
    <div class="wrap">
        <form action="" method="post">
            FirstName <input type="text" name="firstNametxt" value="" /><br/>
            LastName   <input type="text" name="lastNametxt" value="" /><br/>
            email <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br/>
            Query <input type="text" name="query" value="" /><br/>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <?php   
            global $wpdb;
                    $firstName = $_POST["firstNametxt"];
                    $lastName = $_POST["lastNametxt"];
                    $email = $_POST["email"];
                    $query = $_POST["query"];

                    echo $firstName;
            $contactus_table = $wpdb->prefix."contactus";

            $sql = "INSERT INTO $contactus_table (id, firstname, lastname, email,                                               

              query, reg_date) VALUES ('2', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $query,

              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";                  

              $wpdb->query($sql)) 

       ?>
       </form>
       </div>

       <?php
            }
            add_shortcode( 'CONUS', 'contactus_shortcode' );

       ?>
  ```

Comment: Why are you sending ID? ID should be Auto Incremented in db.

Comment: yea I don't know, am sorry how should then the code be? can u reassign it accordingly..

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

Comment: How to add with id and time stamp in the row can u tell me?

Comment: @rajesh delete the first item in VALUES (i.e. 2) and the `id, ` after `$contactus_table`

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Thank you so much for your reply...!! Did u check out the last column, what to do with that?

Comment: Why not @RRikesh 's solution is not working on your problem?

Comment: I checked but don't know how to code.. can you help me..!!

Comment: I did that bro... no use

Comment: $wpdb->insert( 
 '$contactus_table', 
 array( 
  'firstname' => '$firstName', 
  'lastname' => '$lastName',
                'email' => '$email',
                'query' => '$query'
 ), 
 array( 
  '%s', 
  '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s'
 ) 
        );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my error in the query, Thank you all guys for responding, I just gave the piece of code

```
  <?php
  global $wpdb;
  $contactus_table = $wpdb->prefix."contactus";
        //error with the query 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $contactus_table (firstname, lastname, email, query, reg_date) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$query', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

               if($wpdb->query($sql)) 
               {
               $BlogName = get_bloginfo();
               echo $BlogName;
               }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself. It's just a frame of what it should be at least. Search more and use the format. The following is not checked, so it's your turn... :)

```
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="first-name-text">First name: </label><input type="text" id="first-name-text" name="firstNametxt" value="" /><br/>
  <label for="last-name-text">Last name: </label><input type="text" id="last-name-text" name="lastNametxt" value="" /><br/>
  <label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" /><br/>
  <label for="query">Query: </label><input type="text" id="query" name="query" value="" /><br/>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

  //get posted value from the form
  $firstName = $_POST["firstNametxt"];
  $lastName = $_POST["lastNametxt"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $query = $_POST["query"];

  //deal with database in WordPress way
  global $wpdb;
  $contactus_table = $wpdb->prefix."contactus";
  $wpdb->insert( 
    $contactus_table, 
    array( 
        'firstname' => $firstName, 
        'lastname'  => $lastName,
        'email'     => $email,
        'query'     => $query,
        'reg_date'  => current_time( 'mysql' ) // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time
    ), 
    array( 
      '%s', //data type is string
      '%s',
      '%s',
      '%s',
      '%s' 
    ) 
  );
}
?>
```

Comment: Not getting added bro.. :(

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/315iexu.jpg Click this url bro this is the structure of the database